# Javascript Replace including prefixed character

Tags: javascript

This is the script I currently have

```
var str = '1PG IND3A 1USBCP 1MLWIEL GRY/WHT'
str = str.replace(/.*MLWIEL/,'')
alert(str)
```

Which returns `GRY/WHT` If I remove the wildcard from the Javascript it returns this `1PG IND3A 1USBCP 1 GRY/WHT` what I want to return is `1PG IND3A 1USBCP GRY/WHT` The `1` that was standing alone has been removed.

How can I achieve this? The number may not always be 1 it could be 1-99? A

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this if before MLWIEL must be a number and a whitespace:

```
str = str.replace(/\s[0-9]+MLWIEL/,'')
```

if before it there must be a whitespace (at least one)

Description:
You have used `.*MLWIEL` regex, which means: any string that is ending with `MLWIEL`. 
 Dot stands for any character, whereas * any number of occurences (>=0).

If you go with `[0-9]+` it will mean a number , `\s` a whitespace.

Comment: No problem:) Glad I could help.